# Создание apk файла для Android из программного кода Python с помощью python-for-android

Tags: android, python, pyqt5

Хочу скомпилировать своё приложение, написанное на питон в файл apk с последующей возможностью добавление в плэй маркет. Изучил множество вариантов и пытался это сделать. Но никак не получается. Есть ли какое то простое решение? Приведу пример приложения:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

app = QApplication([])

mw = QWebEngineView()
mw.load(QUrl("https://ru.stackoverflow.com"))
mw.setEnabled(False)
mw.show()

QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: mw.setEnabled(True))

app.exec()
```

Это не совсем моё приложение но хотя бы такой простой вариант скомпилировать было бы очень здорово.

Сейчас присматриваюсь к python-for-android. Есть достаточно обширный репозиторий на гитхабе - https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android
На сколько я понимаю, можно собрать достаточно просто. Но сколько бы я не читал инструкцию никак не получается разобраться.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, если это не является большой проблемой. Или может быть есть какой то мануал в русскоязычном или англоязычном интернете, в котором пошагово разбирался бы процесс сборки простого приложения на примере.

Спасибо за вашу помощь!